# Change SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio theme to dark

Tags: visual-studio-2013, themes, management-studio-express

I change the color theme of Visual Studio to dark. It's very cool, especially for my eyes.

I also very often use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The problem is when I change from Visual Studio to SQL Server Management Studio it's a pain for my eyes.

Is there is a simple way to change SQL Server Management Studio's theme to dark, too?

Comment: No, SSMS is *based* on Visual Studio, but as far as I know, it doesn't support themes (yet?). But with VS 2013, there's not much need for SSMS anymore - you can do most of the database related tasks directly in VS with whatever theme you want to use

Comment: It’s a good solution but in Visual Studio I can’t make backups or restores easily.

Comment: Just learn to write the `BACKUP DATABASE ...` T-SQL statement and you can use it in Visual Studio ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the link below for a .zip file that contains a Visual Studio project. Open the project and if necessary, edit the SRC_KEY and DEST_KEY strings to reflect the versions of Visual Studio and SQL Server you're running. I believe the GUID value of the key remains unchanged.

After you run the project and it finishes successfully, open up SQL Server Management Studio, go to Tools -> Options. Then click "Environment" on the left, and then "Fonts and Colors." You should see they have changed to dark ones. Just click the "OK" button and you should be good to go.

If you're wary of copying registry values, just make a backup of your SQL Server registry settings. Good luck; I hope that helps!

[Dark colour theme for SQL Server Management Studio](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1646/dark-colour-theme-for-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: Because I work with VS Express I try with this keys: 
       Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\FontAndColors\{A27B4E24-A735-4D1D-B8E7-9716E1E3D8E0}

       Software\Microsoft\VSTA\9.0\FontAndColors\{A27B4E24-A735-4D1D-B8E7-9716E1E3D8E0} The program works fine but no changes in SQL Management Studio.